# Redux Form, Radio Button Fields, how to support variable values?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

In my react redux form, I have the following:

```
        <fieldset className="form-group">
          <legend>Radio buttons</legend>
          {this.props.job_titles.map(jobTitle => (
          <div className="form-check" key={jobTitle.id}>
            <label className="form-check-label">
              <Field
                name="job_title_id"
                component="input"
                type="radio"
                value={jobTitle.id}
              />
              {' '}
              {jobTitle.title}
            </label>
          </div>
          ))}
        </fieldset>
```

This renders the radio buttons correctly, but when you click to select a radio button, the radio button never sets as selected. You can't select an option - the form is broken.

What's strange is if I update: `value={jobTitle.id}` to `value="anything"` then the radio buttons can be selected.

I'm not seeing anything in the redux form docs about radio buttons dynamically generated. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: these are radio buttons not checkboxes...

Comment: Can you add the code with the `<input>` element?

Comment: @sissonb meaning how it is rendering in the browser?

Comment: I wanted to see what the `<Field>` element was doing, but I found it here. http://redux-form.com/6.8.0/docs/api/Field.md/

Comment: Am I using `<Field>` incorrectly?

Comment: You're going to need to manage the `input.checked` property. http://redux-form.com/6.8.0/docs/api/Field.md/#-input-checked-boolean-optional-

Comment: but it's a radio button? mind providing an example? Thanks

Comment: Interesting, adding `checked={this.props.job_titles.id}` made it work... not sure I get why :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the checked property to a `state` or `prop`, then update that in the click handler.

```jsx
<Field
    onClick={
        () => {
            this.setState((prevState) => {
                return {isChecked: !prevState.isChecked};
            });
        }
    }
    name="job_title_id"
    component="input"
    type="radio"
    checked={this.state.isChecked}
    value={jobTitle.id}
/>
```

Answer (score 8):

Convert value to String:

```
<Field
            name="job_title_id"
            component="input"
            type="radio"
            value={jobTitle.id.toString()}
          />
```